# Ignoring a system call

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, ptrace

I know that you can trap a system call by using **ptrace**. But what I wanna do is to ignore a system call. So is that possible for **ptrace** to trap a system call, see its number and if the number is of a system call that has to be ignored, the **ptrace** stops the system call from proceeding or have the system call return immediately.

The point is that we should have the effect of having the application ignore particular system calls by using **ptrace**.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `PTRACE_GETREGS` and `PTRACE_SETREGS`.
If you change `eip` to be after the system call, and `eax` to make the return value valid, the call may be skipped.
But I didn't try it, and wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: Changing eip to be after the system call! That is not easy my friend :(!

Comment: @MettalicPriest: not easy, but in order to change the behavior of the ptraced program, you're going to need to muck around with the internals of its machine state.